# Converting Polygons QGIS can read

Tags: qgis

I have tried multiple times to import CSV file and show the Polygons on QGIS, but I failed, it's only recognize points...

Polygons field is look like this:

```
[[25.113052980166977,46.435153157670314],[25.09740981672634,46.4084421466916],[25.116122341878267,46.39442558623208],[25.132026478296783,46.42158078241842],[25.113052980166977,46.435153157670314]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What were the precise steps that you performed when you tried to do this using QGIS?

Comment: I've tried to import it through delimited text ( i've tried all the option there ) and I've tried shape tool plugin, and Geometry tool at the vector section, but it seems it can't read it, cause nothing change at all, sorry for my explanation, but I'm actually newbie in this field

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Polygons are a series of lines that close. Lines are features between two points. Your example has 5 lat-long or long-lat point definitions with the last corresponding to the first- that is, it is closed back to its origin. I don't recognize the input format but if you can read it as points then you can convert those points to a polygon. However, if there are more than one polygons in your input then they need some identifier to show how the points of one should be recognized as unique from the points of another.

Comment: Try to process the csv to make the polygons field to appear as [wkt formatted polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry). For exampe using excel then import the csv to QGIS